# xhr.js:220 GET http://infura-ipfs/io/ipfs/QmPCfbFjcjf9xZmDzoCQfwdVpKhJCx4sS4FU3RPWfRSrDs net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: ipfs

error:
xhr.js:220                           GET http://infura-ipfs/io/ipfs/QmPCfbFjcjf9xZmDzoCQfwdVpKhJCx4sS4FU3RPWfRSrDs net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
:
"ERR_NETWORK"
config
:
{transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
message
:
"Network Error"
name
:
"AxiosError"
request
:
XMLHttpRequest {data: undefined, onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, …}
response
:
XMLHttpRequest {data: undefined, onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, …}
[[Prototype]]
:
Error

stuck at this error
could anyone pls help me